# Forked repository package not installed with npm 5

Tags: node.js, git, github

**Description:**  I have installed `npm 5.4.2` and `node 8.7.0`

**Issue** : When I run `npm install` command, npm installs successfully, but forked repo package is not installed. Please help me.

It's worked fine with npm version 3.10.10

Comment: You should clone forked repo package yourself. `npm install` is for installing necessary dependencies for forked repo package. You use this command inside the forked repo package folder.

Comment: i used into angular 4. when i fire ng serve command that time '@micc83\fontIconPicker\jquery.fonticonpicker.js' not found error throw

Comment: As you can see the link to .js file is invalid. You cannot make link to external GitHub project file inside your project.